# 特殊なアルファベット文字の置換

Tags: python, python3

特殊なアルファベット文字を使った外国人名を一般的なアルファベットに置き換えたいと思っています。例えばBjörn BorgをBjorn Borgに、Emily Brontëに、というようにです。

このようなコードを書きました。

```
import re
specials = "ëö"
name = input()
for i in name:
    if i == specials:
        name = name.replace('ë', 'e').replace('ö', 'o')
    else:
        break
print(name)
```

その結果、エラーメッセージは出ないのですが、名前は元のままです。どのように改善すれば良いでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 丁寧な回答をありがとうございました。大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「特殊な文字か」はあまり関係がなく、かつ `for` ループの処理が不要な気がします。

恐らく置換対象の文字を含むかを事前にチェックしつつ処理しようとしているのかと思われますが、`replace` 等は置換対象の文字を含まなければそのまま "何もしない" だけので、素直に呼び出すだけで済みそうです。

```
import re
name = input()
name = name.replace('ë', 'e').replace('ö', 'o')
print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

以下は [str.maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) と [str.translate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) を使う方法です。

```py
specials = ('ëö', 'eo')
name = input()
name = name.translate(str.maketrans(*specials))
print(name)
```

`input()` ではなくテストデータで確認してみます。

```py
specials = ('ëö', 'eo')
names = ('Björn Borg', 'Emily Brontë')

for name in names:
  trans = name.translate(str.maketrans(*specials))
  print(f'{name} => {trans}')

## 実行結果
Björn Borg => Bjorn Borg
Emily Brontë => Emily Bronte
```